# What are my options for fixing a broken handle on the bib?

Tags: plumbing

[image: bibb top view]
[image: bibb side view]

Part of the handle broke off. There is a lot of corrosion(?) around the handle connection. I think the whole bib looks very solidly attached/soldered to the T.

What are my options for fixing this?

I could try to replace the handle, but I’m concerned that I will break the screw that is holding the handle to the bib.

Update: the screw head looks like this now.

[image: screw head close up]

Comment: Yup it is solid , take the screw out and remove the handle go to a plumbing or big box store and get a new handle or replace the entire stem and jamb nut. Or the complete faucet there are 3 options.

Comment: @EdBeal  This looks like an answer. Type it up.

Comment: I just tried to take the screw out and the Phillips notch got shredded. :(. Time to call a plumber?  They probably have to replace the whole thing?

Comment: Those screws are usually soft brass if you just heat the top some times that will break the oxides or hard water deposits enough to allow it to loosen up with the slot method, worst case if the screw breaks you can remove the handle, if you want to have the handle held on with a screw turn the water off unscrew the jam nut then take the stem out and get a new one a plumber is going to cost $$$ parts are cheap and replace the rubber seat while at it all home owners should know how to do this simple maintenance repair. Advantage no more drips and you don’t have to turn so hard the handle breaks.

Answer (score 1):

Call a plumber if you want.

If you'd like to do more, carefully cut a slot in the head of the screw using a fine-tooth hacksaw. Over several days, regularly spray a penetrant such as PartsBlaster (no affiliation) onto the screw. Tap gently on and around the screw with a small hammer.

After a few days, use a flat-bladed screwdriver whose bit fits tightly in the slot you've just cut. Then, while pushing the screwdriver down into the screw, try to turn the screw to remove it.

If it works, you can easily replace the handle. If it doesn't, you're no worse off.

Comment: I will give that a try tomorrow.

Comment: @milesmeow And you could try the remove-the-stem method described by Ed Beal in comments above.

Comment: I don’t know how old this bib is. Do you think that there is a suitable replacement for the stem? Is that the part where the handle is attached to?

Comment: @milesmeow Yes. Go to a hardware store, and you'll see similar bibs; the design hasn't changed in decades. And if the design or size is different and this tactic doesn't work, you can still retreat to the plumber.